# Can run jar from commandline but not in shell script - why?

Tags: java, linux, shell, rest, jar

I want t start a jar which should provide a Rest-WebService.
When I run following command from terminal the jar and the webservice starts successfully:

```
java -jar SchnittprofilService-1.0-fat.jar BH121 8888
```

If I run the same command in a shell script `start.sh`, the jar starts but the not the webservice.

The permission for `start.sh` is set to 777.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the content of your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops:

You have to put your arguments in quotation marks:

```
java -jar SchnittprofilService-1.0-fat.jar "BH121" "8888"
```